# Positions in array where points fall inside a circle?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of (x,y) coordinates, and I just want to get the elements in the list where the point `x,y` falls within a radius `r`.

What I am doing is this:

```
a = {{1,0},{0,1},{2,2}}

Position[a,  Sqrt[(#[[1]])^2 + (#[[2]])^2] < 2 &]
```

But this returns nothing.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `Position[a, _?(Sqrt[(#[[1]])^2 + (#[[2]])^2] < 2 &), {1}, 
 Heads -> False]`?

Comment: or, shorter, `Position[a, _?(Norm[#] < 2 &), {1}, Heads -> False]`?

Comment: Yes this works thanks! If you make your comment into an answer I'll accept it. Why does it work though? What have I done wrong?

Comment: @SuperCiocia `Position` takes a pattern as its second argument.

Comment: And I wasn't giving it a pattern?

Comment: @SuperCiocia http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Introduction-Patterns.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Position[a, _?(Sqrt[(#[[1]])^2 + (#[[2]])^2] < 2 &), {1}, Heads -> False]
```

> {{1}, {2}}

Alternatively,

```
Position[a, _?(Norm[#] < 2 &), {1}, Heads -> False]
Position[a, {x_, y_} /; Norm[{x, y}] < 2, {1}]
Position[a, {x_, y_} /; Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 2, {1}]
```

also give the same result.

Answer (score 3):

You might prefer to use `Select`

```
a = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {2, 2}};

Select[a, Sqrt[(#[[1]])^2 + (#[[2]])^2] < 2 &]
```

This gives

> {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}

Might be more natural if you want the values rather than their position.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new list by

```
NewList = {};
r = 2;
Table[If[InRadius[a[[n, 1]], a[[n, 2]], r], NewList = Append[NewList, a[[n]]]], {n, 1, 3}];
NewList
```

> {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the combination `Select` along with `RegionMember`

```
In[81]:= Clear[a, reg]
a = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {2, 2}};
reg = Disk[{0, 0}, 2];
Select[a, RegionMember[reg, #] &]

Out[84]= {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}
```

Visualize the result

```
Graphics[{LightGray, Opacity[0.5], EdgeForm[Dashed], Disk[{0, 0}, 2]},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.015], Point[a]}, Axes -> True, 
 PlotRange -> 4]
```

[image]

The advantage of this method is that you can easily change the disk's radius *and center*. Or specify your custom implicit region

```
In[92]:= Clear[reg]
reg = ImplicitRegion[{y < 2 - x^2, y > x^2 - 2}, {x, y}];
Select[a, RegionMember[reg, #] &]

Out[94]= {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}
```

Here is the plot

```
RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion@reg, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.015], Point[a]}, Axes -> True, 
 PlotRange -> 4, Frame -> False]
```

[image]